# CSS: how to have <divs> reposition relative to a centered background image

Tags: html, css

I currently have a div with a `background` image which has `background-position:center` set. 
Inside of this div I have a bunch of `<a>` tags that have `<img>` children. I would ideally like these `<a>` tags to be position in an exact relationship to the centered background image. Currently their position is set to `relative` which only maintains the ideal relationship to the background image for one particular viewport width. Is there a way that I can have the elements move along with the background image in the desired relationship without using JS?

Here is my CSS and html

haml:

```
#map
  %a#saddleback_point
   =image_tag('saddleback_college.png', width:'300px')
  %a#citrus_point
    =image_tag('citrus_college.png', width:'300px')
  %a#sonrise_point
    =image_tag('sonrise.png', width:'300px')
  %a#vegas_point
    =image_tag('vegas.png', width:'300px')
  %a#tennessee_point
    =image_tag('tennessee.png', width:'300px')
  %a#chestnut_point
    =image_tag('chestnut.png', width:'300px')
  %a#saint_point
    =image_tag('saint.png', width:'300px')
  %a#boston_point
    =image_tag('boston.png', width:'300px')
  %a#fisher_point
   =image_tag('fisher.png', width:'300px')
```

CSS:

```
#map{
  margin-top:200px;
  background: url(image_path("vereinigte_staaten.png"));  
//  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 650px;
  width:100%;
}

 #saddleback_point {
  //display:none;
  position:relative;
  font-size:30pt;
  top:200px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:300px;
 }
 #citrus_point{
   top:112px;
   bottom:0px;
   left:45px;
   position:relative;
 }

 #chestnut_point{
   top:220px;
   bottom:0px;
   left:-290px;
   position:relative;
 }

 #vegas_point{
   top:385px;
   bottom:0px;
   left:-360px;
   position:relative;
 }

 #tennessee_point{
   top:405px;
   bottom:0px;
   left:-250px;
   position:relative;
 }
 #saint_point{
   top:-130px;
   bottom:0px;
   left:1260px;
   position:relative;
 }
#boston_point{
  top:-190px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:1010px;
 position:relative;
}
#fisher_point{
  top:-270px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:700px;
  position:relative;
}

#sonrise_point{
 top:395px;
 bottom:0px;
 left:-300px;
 position:relative;
}
```

[image: Perfect relationship of bckgd and foreground]
[image: larger viewport]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the container to `position: relative` and the inner elements to `position: absolute`. That will allow you to position them precisely in relation to the container.